# How to run Socket.io Chat Demo? Error on ..//

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

Hello I am new to programming and was trying to run the socket.io chat demo. However, when I try running it it gives me a error which is found at line 5 saying it can't find ('../..'). Can someone explain to me why this is happening?

Heres a snippet of the code where the issue is at:

```js
// Setup basic express server
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('../..')(server);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

server.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
});

// Routing
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// Chatroom
```

The source code of the full thing is on [Github](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/tree/master/examples/chat)

Comment: Your code shud run without any error, if you have followed the [How to use](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/tree/master/examples/chat#how-to-use) properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line. In the example they have on github it works, because it links to the socket.io library which is in the root folder.

```
var io = require('../..')(server);
```

In your case if you are trying to lauch just this example and not the whole socket.io folder you need to install socket.io library with [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/).

```
npm install --save socket.io
```

After downloading the library you can require it directly:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I know what that is. I also found out I was running npm install socket command wrong also.

Comment: `--save` flag is not necessary, it just adds dependency to the `package.json` file